# Quarkus AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem not working as expection

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-extension

what i am trying to do is to build an Quarkus extention that will change some annotations at quarkus application

so I used AnnotationTransformerBuildItem.

```
package com.tawfeek.greeting.extension.deployment;

import io.quarkus.arc.deployment.AdditionalBeanBuildItem;
import io.quarkus.arc.deployment.AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem;
import io.quarkus.arc.processor.AnnotationsTransformer;
import io.quarkus.builder.item.MultiBuildItem;
import io.quarkus.deployment.annotations.BuildStep;
import io.quarkus.deployment.annotations.ExecutionTime;
import io.quarkus.deployment.annotations.Record;
import io.quarkus.deployment.builditem.FeatureBuildItem;
import io.quarkus.deployment.recording.RecorderContext;
import io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ClassTransformingBuildStep;

import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.Recorder;
import org.jboss.jandex.AnnotationTarget;
import org.jboss.jandex.DotName;
import org.jboss.jandex.MethodInfo;

import java.util.function.Predicate;

import static io.quarkus.arc.ComponentsProvider.LOG;


class GreetingExtensionProcessor {

    private static final String FEATURE = "greeting-extension";

    @BuildStep
    FeatureBuildItem feature() {
        return new FeatureBuildItem(FEATURE);
    }



    @BuildStep
    AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem transform() {

        return new AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem(new AnnotationsTransformer() {
            @Override
            public boolean appliesTo(AnnotationTarget.Kind kind) {
                return kind == AnnotationTarget.Kind.METHOD;
            }
            @Override
            public void transform(TransformationContext context) {
                MethodInfo methodInfo = context.getTarget().asMethod();
                if (methodInfo.hasAnnotation("jakarta.ws.rs.GET")) {
                    // Remove the existing @GET annotation
                    context.transform()
                            .remove(annotationInstance -> annotationInstance.name()
                                    .equals(DotName.createSimple("jakarta.ws.rs.GET"))).done();
                    // Add the @POST annotation
                    context.transform().add(DotName.createSimple("jakarta.ws.rs.POST")).done();
                    System.out.println("method "+methodInfo.name()+" is change from get to post");
                }
            }
        });
    }



}
```

the problem is that when add the code to the app and run it. the result is it print that it change the method `method hello is change from get to post`
put actually it still using get not post when testing using postman

I expect there is a configuration for the quarkus extension to affect the beans Methods and it then work correctly

Comment: There are two classes in Quarkus named `AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem`. Make sure you don't use the one from ArC and do use the one from RESTEasy Reactive.

Comment: can you give me the doc @Ladicek or the full name of the class to import after adding rest easy reactive to the project because I Can't reach on the internet